# getting indivdul cell from DataTable from CellClickEvent

Tags: c#, winforms, collections, datatable

I am new to DataTables and am trying to access individual cells opposed to rows and colls. I have inseretd an array of data through the findResult 
which is from an exsiting webService. I am now trying to access the 'Id' column, but the individual cell that the user will click on. I will then stored this in a var to be used for further processing within the class.

I have populated my datatable as follows:

```
            DataTable ss = new DataTable();
            ss.Columns.Add("ID");
            ss.Columns.Add("Text");
            ss.Columns.Add("Highlight");
            ss.Columns.Add("Cursor");
            ss.Columns.Add("Description");
            ss.Columns.Add("Next");

            DataRow row = ss.NewRow();
            row["ID"] = findResults[0].Id;
            row["Text"] = findResults[0].Text;
            row["Highlight"] = findResults[0].Highlight;
            row["Cursor"] = findResults[0].Cursor;
            row["Description"] = findResults[0].Description;
            row["Next"] = findResults[0].Next;
            ss.Rows.Add(row);

            if (txt_Search.Text.Length <= 2 || txt_Search.Text.Length >= 9)
            { MessageBox.Show("Please enter more than 2 Chars!!"); }

            foreach (DataRow itemDrow in ss.Rows)
            {

                foreach (var item in findResults)
                {
                    var num = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value = item.Id.ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value = item.Text.ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value = item.Highlight.ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[3].Value = item.Cursor.ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[4].Value = item.Description.ToString();
                    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[5].Value = item.Next.ToString();
                }
            }
```

And this is how I have attempted to acheive my click event however it was only returning the first row and coll of the varaible 'ID' and not regestering that i had clicked on another cell.

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            string value1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string value2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string SerachId = findResults[0].Id.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(SerachId);
            //...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`DataGridViewCellEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `CellClick` event exposes two Properties: `ColumnIndex` and `RowIndex` which will tell you which cell the user has clicked. Once you have the [`DataGridViewCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value(v=vs.110).aspx) getting the `Value` is easy.

Example:

```
var clickedCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
var value = clickedCell.Value;
```

Comment: Cheers this gets me the Index of the coll and row, but how does one use the index to acces the data within that specific cell? Should i use a for loop to itterate through?  this is what i get back in my output        DataGridViewTextBoxCell { ColumnIndex=0, RowIndex=5 }

Comment: @whatdoyouNeedFromMe use the Value property.

Comment: Cheers allready found it thanks for you answer was very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

After having a little play around and using @Kempeths response I solved it as follows, this now prints out the information in every cell thats double clicked thanks:

```
 public void dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
        if (clickedCell != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString());
            string SerachId = clickedCell.ToString();
        }
```